# How do I edit one selected row in GridView on a button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a GridView with 4 columns and I would like to edit one row in a selected column on a button click, I want to replace my value in the column from ON to OFF, as my button says.

So  when I click the OFF button the column "STATUS" will be changed to OFF from ON.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sooooo many tutorials on this.

This is one of the **most basic operations** with a `GridView`, did you ever Google it?

You can see [here](http://devilswork.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/gridview-row-edit-delete-and-update/) to start and then **learn more** what you can do with the `GridView` [here](http://www.highoncoding.com/Categories/7_GridView_Control.aspx)

---

Assuming you are using jQuery to simplify the code

```
<asp:button id="btnOnOff" 
            runat="server" 
            text="<# Eval("cellOnOff") %>"
            onclientclick="changeStatus(this, '<# Eval("cellOnOff") %>');" />
<asp:hidden id="hfId"
            value="<# Eval("cellId") %>" />
```

and then

```
var g_elem = '';

function changeStatus(elem, type) {

    g_elem = elem;

    // let's say we are changing
    $(elem).val("changing...");

    // let's get the id
    var id = $(elem).prent().find("#hfId").val();

    // let's send info to our page to precess and wait for an answer
    $.get('ajax/changeStatus.ashx', 
          { changeFrom: type, id: id },
          function(data) {
              // got the answer, let's show it
              $(g_elem).val(data);
          }
    );
}
```

and your handler just get's the `id` and the `changeFrom` from the query string and sends back the new value `ON` or `OFF`...

Comment: just set the value in javascript and sent an async call to change the value on the DB... or better yet, change to `changing...` and when you get a good answer back from the async call, change it to the correct operation.

Comment: added the idea behind what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in Gridviw_ItemCommand event

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution for your question
https://softwarestech.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/get-selected-row-from-grid-to-textbox/